# Animation of double pendulum with a spring (3DOF)

Tags: differential-equations, physics, animation

I've got a problem with animating a double pendulum where the first mass is connected with a ceiling with a bar and the second mass is connected with the first one with a spring. Below is my code which doesn't work and the reason is `"Coordinate {ReplaceAll[Sin[ph[0]], NDSolve[{False, False, False, False, False, 0, False, False, 0}, {s, ph, th}, {t, 0, 100}]], ReplaceAll[-Cos[ph[0]], NDSolve[{False, False, False, False should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."` What did I make wrong?

```
m1 = 1; m2 = 1; l1 = 1; l2 = 1; k = 1/10; g = 9.81;
lagrangian := 
  m1*l1^2*ph'[t]^2/2 + 
   m2*((l1 Cos[ph[t]] ph'[t] + Sin[th[t]] s'[t] + 
          Cos[th[t]] (l2 + s[t]) th'[t])^2 + (-l1 Sin[ph[t]] ph'[t] + 
          Sin[th[t]] s'[t] + Cos[th[t]] (l2 + s[t]) th'[t])^2 + 
       s'[t]^2/2)/2 + m1*9.81*l1*Cos[ph[t]] + 
   m2*9.81*(l1*Cos[ph[t]] + (l2 + s[t])*Sin[th[t]]) - k*s[t]^2/2;
eq1 := D[D[lagrangian, s'[t]], t] - D[lagrangian, s[t]] == 0;
eq2 := D[D[lagrangian, ph'[t]], t] - D[lagrangian, ph[t]] == 0;
eq3 := D[D[lagrangian, th'[t]], t] - D[lagrangian, th[t]] == 0;
sol := NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, s[0] == 1/2, ph[0] == Pi/2, th[0] = 0, 
   s'[0] == 0, ph'[0] == 0, th'[0] = 0}, {s, ph, th}, {t, 0, 100}]

x1[t_] := l1*Sin[ph[t]] /. sol
y1[t_] := -l1*Cos[ph[t]] /. sol
x2[t_] := l1*Sin[ph[t]] + (l2 + s[t])*Sin[th[t]] /. sol
y2[t_] := -l1*Cos[ph[t]] - (l2 + s[t])*Sin[th[t]] /. sol

d = 5;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{{x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}}], 
   Disk[{x2[t], y2[t]}, 0.05]}, PlotRange -> {{-d, d}, {-d, d}}], {t, 
  0, 10}]
```

My Lagrangian is as follows:

$$\frac{m_1l_1^2\dot{\varphi}^2}{2}+\frac{m_2}{2}(l_1^2\dot{\varphi}^2+2l_2^2\dot{\theta}^2\cos^2\theta+2\dot{s}^2\sin^2\theta+4\dot{s}s\dot{\theta}\cos\theta+2s^2\theta^2\cos^2\theta+\dot{s}^2)+m_1gl_1\cos\varphi+m_2g(l_1\cos\varphi+(l_2+s)\sin\theta)-\frac{ks^2}{2}$$

One can check the correctness of the KE within the Lagrangian by checking the sums of (squared) tangent velocities which are:

$$\dot{x}_1=l_1\dot{\varphi}\cos\varphi,$$ $$\dot{y}_1=l_1\dot{\varphi}\sin\varphi,$$ $$\dot{x}_2=(l_1\dot{\varphi}\cos\varphi+l_2\dot{\theta}\cos\theta)+(\dot{s}\sin\theta+s\dot{\theta}\cos\theta),$$ $$\dot{y}_2=(l_1\dot{\varphi}\sin\varphi-l_2\dot{\theta}\cos\theta)-(\dot{s}\sin\theta+s\dot{\theta}\cos\theta),$$

and the normal velocity of the spring which is $\dot{s}$. The PE of the Lagrangian is: $$-m_1gl_1\cos\varphi-m_2g(l_1\cos\varphi+(l_2+s)\sin\theta)+\frac{ks^2}{2}.$$

Thanks in advance.[image: the graphic]

Comment: Check your constraints in `NDSolve` , they must be defined with "==" not "="

Comment: Running your code one command at a time leads to the following. When trying to use `sol` (causing it to be evaluated) I get a bunch of division by zero errors.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I tried putting extra `=` to my code, however, it didn't help.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen do you mean a bunch of `False` things in `NDSolve`?

Comment: Further testing (with a narrower interval for $t$, and modified initial values) revealed the following problem: `x1[t]` is not a number, rather it is a list of length one. I haven't used `NDSolve` but may be it is like all the other variants of solving equations, and outputs a list of solutions. If I edit your commands to read like `x1[t_] := l1*Sin[ph[t]] /. sol[[1]]` at least that problem goes away.

Comment: I don't know why those infinites emerge, but when I try it with a non-zero initial value for `th[0]`, the infinities go away. Depending on a choice (and the range of `t`) Mathematica then outputs an error message about hitting a singularity and/or step size zero. After a bit of testing I found ranges, where it goes through. Fixing the above data type error also, then leads to a situation where `Manipulate` shows something, but I'm not sure it is what you expected to see :-(

Comment: Gotta go now. Good luck hunting the bug!

Comment: @DenisD.Bavrin `NDSolve[...,Method -> { "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]` gives the error "NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.6957675004278504`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected." To check your equations please provide a scetch of your system. I don't understand "where the first mass is connected with a ceiling with a bar and..."

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I added the illustration, thanks! And `s` in the code above stands for a displacement of the length $l_2$ of the undeformed spring. $\varphi_1$ is `ph[t]`, $\varphi_2$ is `th[t]`.

Comment: Something is just wrong with the differential equations. If I use `th[0]==0` it leads to division by zero error. A non-zero value leads to a similar error message @UlrichNeumann described. If I constrain the interval of `t` to not reach that offending  value, then the call to `sol` goes through.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen hm, could you be that kindest to review my equations? I did my best by recalculating these by means of Mathematica. To be precise, I calculated velocities of the points and summed their squares and so on. Thus, I got KE and PE for the Lagrangian. Alas, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you write me on email? d.bavrin@g.nsu.ru

Comment: I suspect that there is some surprise / hidden assumption of what exactly Mathematica outputs in response to `NDSolve`. After the above steps I can make the calculations go through. But in the end there are no values to for example `ph[0]`. The animation shows a variable length line segment with a bob at one end, but its angle doesn't change. Mathematica has certain surprises, and the output is not always what you would expect.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so what should we do? In the case of a regular double pendulum program gives an OK solution (animation), but in this case it gives nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't the potential energy have a term like $-m_2g(\ell+s)\cos\theta$. instead of $\sin\theta$. At least the calculations go through with that change in place! The animation still doesn't look right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149491/discussion-between-denis-d-bavrin-and-jyrki-lahtonen).

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution

parameters (changed k !)

```
m1 = 1; m2 = 1; l1 = 1; l2 = 1; k =100(* 1/10*); g = 9.81;
```

geometry

```
{e1, e2} = IdentityMatrix[2];
e[phi_] := e1 Sin[phi] + e2 Cos[phi]
p1 = l1 e[\[CurlyPhi]1[t]];  (* position m1 *)
p2 = l1 e[\[CurlyPhi]1[t]] + (l2 + s[t]) e[\[CurlyPhi]2[t]]; (*position m2 *)
```

Energies

```
T = 1/2 m1 D[p1, t] . D[p1, t] + 1/2 m2 D[p2, t] . D[p2, t] //Expand // FullSimplify
U = m1 g p1 . (-e2) + m2 g p2 . (-e2) + 1/2 k s[t]^2
```

Lagrange

```
lagrangian = T - U;
var = {s[t], \[CurlyPhi]1[t], \[CurlyPhi]2[t]};
eqn = D[D[lagrangian, {D[var, t]}] , t] - D[lagrangian, {var  }] ;
```

solution (changed s[0]==m2 g/k end simualtion time )

```
sol = NDSolve[{Map[# == 0 &, eqn], 
s[0] ==  m2 g/k(*1/2*), \[CurlyPhi]1[0] == Pi/2, \[CurlyPhi]2[0] ==0,s'[0] == 0, \[CurlyPhi]1'[0] == 0, \[CurlyPhi]2'[0] ==0}
,{s, \[CurlyPhi]1, \[CurlyPhi]2}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]];

Plot[Evaluate[{s[t], \[CurlyPhi]1[t], \[CurlyPhi]2[t]} /. sol] , {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

animation

```
P1 = Function[t, Evaluate[DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1}] . (p1 /. sol)]] ;
P2 = Function[t, Evaluate[DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1}] . (p2 /. sol)]] ;
Manipulate[
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, P1[t], P1[t] + P2[t]} ],Point[{{0, 0}, P1[t], P1[t] + P2[t]}]} , 
PlotRange ->{3 {-1, 1}, 4 {-1, 0}}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!